# Converting Text file to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file called dict1.txt that contains two lines and I'd like to make the first string to give the keys and the second to give the values. The text file is

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> gikaclmnqrpoxzybdefhjstuvw

and the code I've been toying with is:

```
def read_cipherdef(fn):
d = {}
fn = open('dict1.txt', 'r')
for line in fn:
    key, val = line.split()
    d[(key)] = val
```

but in this case line.split() doesn't actually split the first line by character and it also gives a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).

Also I'm aware `list(map(''.join, zip(*[iter('dict1.txt')]*1)))` would split them up individually, but using that in conjunction with the existing code gives me another ValueError. So my question would be: how would I use all of this info here together to achieve my desired dictionary?

Thanks.

Comment: How should the output dictionary look ?

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan Great minds think alike

Comment: `int(key)` but keys aren't digits.

Comment: @SuperSaiyan  I'd like it to be be like {'a': 'g', 'b': 'i', 'c': 'k'... etc}

Comment: Instead of map, you can do `list(line)` to split strings into characters.

Comment: @tdelaney ah true, I think it's better now

Comment: I'm going with `dict(zip(*filter(str.strip, open('test.txt').readlines()[:2])))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you can achieve that. Essentially, read the two lines, zip them and use them in a dict-comprehension.

```
>>> with open("/tmp/t") as f:
...     line1 = f.readline().strip()
...     line2 = f.readline().strip()
...     print({x:y for x, y in zip(line1, line2)})
... 
{'a': 'g', 'b': 'i', 'c': 'k', 'd': 'a', 'e': 'c', 'f': 'l', 'g': 'm', 'h': 'n', 'i': 'q', 'j': 'r', 'k': 'p', 'l': 'o', 'm': 'x', 'n': 'z', 'o': 'y', 'p': 'b', 'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'h', 'u': 'j', 'v': 's', 'w': 't', 'x': 'u', 'y': 'v', 'z': 'w'}
```

.. Or if you want a one-liner (this assumes there are only 2 lines in the file):

```
>>> with open("/tmp/t") as f:
...     print({x: y for x, y in zip(*[list(x.strip()) for x in f])})
... 
{'a': 'g', 'b': 'i', 'c': 'k', 'd': 'a', 'e': 'c', 'f': 'l', 'g': 'm', 'h': 'n', 'i': 'q', 'j': 'r', 'k': 'p', 'l': 'o', 'm': 'x', 'n': 'z', 'o': 'y', 'p': 'b', 'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'h', 'u': 'j', 'v': 's', 'w': 't', 'x': 'u', 'y': 'v', 'z': 'w'}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
with open('dict1.txt') as f:
    lines=[line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]
    d=dict(zip(lines[0],lines[1]))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(d)
```

Result:

```
{'a': 'g',
 'b': 'i',
 'c': 'k',
 'd': 'a',
 'e': 'c',
 'f': 'l',
 'g': 'm',
 'h': 'n',
 'i': 'q',
 'j': 'r',
 'k': 'p',
 'l': 'o',
 'm': 'x',
 'n': 'z',
 'o': 'y',
 'p': 'b',
 'q': 'd',
 'r': 'e',
 's': 'f',
 't': 'h',
 'u': 'j',
 'v': 's',
 'w': 't',
 'x': 'u',
 'y': 'v',
 'z': 'w'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can, also, do it like this way:

```
data = (k.rstrip() for k in open("dict1.txt", 'r'))
a = {k:v for k,v in zip(*data)}
print(a)
```

Or maybe in one line:

```
a = {k:v for k,v in zip(*(k.rstrip() for k in open("dict1.txt", 'r')))}
print(a)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'g', 'y': 'v', 'k': 'p', 'j': 'r', 'f': 'l', 'g': 'm', 'o': 'y', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 'b': 'i', 'e': 'c', 'u': 'j', 't': 'h', 'z': 'w', 'l': 'o', 'c': 'k', 'h': 'n', 'i': 'q', 'n': 'z', 'd': 'a', 'w': 't', 'x': 'u', 'v': 's', 'm': 'x', 'p': 'b', 'q': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the comprehension you can use dict directly:

```
dict(zip(*open('dict1.txt', 'rt').read().strip().split()))
```

Output:

```
{'a': 'g', 'b': 'i', 'c': 'k', 'd': 'a', 'e': 'c', 'f': 'l', 'g': 'm', 'h': 'n', 'i': 'q', 'j': 'r', 'k': 'p', 'l': 'o', 'm': 'x', 'n': 'z', 'o': 'y', 'p': 'b', 'q': 'd', 'r': 'e', 's': 'f', 't': 'h', 'u': 'j', 'v': 's', 'w': 't', 'x': 'u', 'y': 'v', 'z': 'w'}
```